# Optional Entity in api.ai

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es, api-ai

I have this intent.

```
Context: asset
Query: When will the @asset fail?

Entity @asset has synonyms "unit, equipment, machine"
```

Now when I query "when will the asset fail? or when will the unit fail?"
It works.

But when I say "when will it fail?"
It does not work.

Is there a way I can make the entity @asset optional?

Comment: as per my understanding, there is a different way to do. when a user asks about " when will it fail " in this case you want to know about "it " and you can ask the user about it @asset.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to deal with that.

When you want an asset, than you set `asset` to required.
Then you use a feature called *slotfilling*. You set a prompt like:

`What asset do you mean?`

User says:

- `When will it fail`
- `When will the unit fail` <-- mark `the unit` as `asset`

In the *Action* segment you may set asset to *required* and set a prompt.
If it is set. API.ai tries to "fill the slot" by showing the user the prompt:
(Example: `What asset do you mean?`)

If required isn't set:
`When will it fail` will be accepted and the asset field is empty. In this case your backend has to handle it. 
Either with a default value or an error message.

Of course it is better for the experience of the user, if he doesn't get a: `I don't know what you mean` response ;-)